# Difference between included SQLite3 library in Python and SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy

I know there is an included library in python for SQLite3, and when I was studying Flask the course instructor proposed to use SQLAlchemy to manage an SQLite database, What´s the difference between using sqlite3 library and SQLAlchemy?

Comment: `sqlite3` is an (embedded) database, SQLAlchemy is a library that interfaces with _other_ databases (MySQL, Postgres, SQLite, etc.).

Comment: and by default the SQLAlchemy dialect for SQLite uses Python's built-in sqlite3 library as its lower-level DBAPI "driver".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLAlchemy is an ORM based tool: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping. It therefore can create and support complex objects, relationships and structures, which is more than an simple API interface with database. I am guessing here, but the SQLite3 library is probably little more than what you need to interface with the database engine. In principle, all database drivers can be used with SQLAlchemy.

I hope this helps.